# How to reduce the number of loops?

Tags: vba, excel

The following code works perfectly. It just works very slowly. Is there any way to speed up/optimize this code?

I think its the amount of loops but I am unable to figure out how to reduce the number of loops without hampering the functionality of the code.

'''

```
Sub inland()

Dim sort As Worksheet
    Set sort = Worksheets("Inland")
Dim buch As Integer
    buch = sort.Cells.Find("Orderbuch", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
Dim name As Integer
    name = sort.Cells.Find("Orderbuchname", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
Dim buysell As Integer
    buysell = sort.Cells.Find("Kauf/Verkauf", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
Dim wkn As Long
    wkn = sort.Cells.Find("WKN", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
Dim lastcolumn As Integer
    lastcolumn = sort.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = sort.Cells(Rows.count, wkn).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To lastrow

Dim a As Long
a = sort.Cells(i, buch).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).Row

If sort.Cells(i, buch).Value = "" And a < lastrow Then
    sort.Cells(i - 1, buch).Copy
    Range(Cells(i, buch), Cells(a, buch)).PasteSpecial
End If
If sort.Cells(i, buch).Value = "" And a >= lastrow Then
    sort.Cells(i - 1, buch).Copy
    Range(Cells(i, buch), Cells(lastrow, buch)).PasteSpecial
End If

If sort.Cells(i - 1, buysell).Value <> "" And sort.Cells(i, name).Value = "" And a < lastrow Then
    sort.Cells(i - 1, buysell).Copy
    Range(Cells(i, buysell), Cells(a, buysell)).PasteSpecial
End If
If sort.Cells(i - 1, buysell).Value <> "" And sort.Cells(i, name).Value = "" And a >= lastrow Then
    sort.Cells(i - 1, buysell).Copy
    Range(Cells(i, buysell), Cells(lastrow, buysell)).PasteSpecial
End If

For j = wkn + 1 To lastcolumn
If sort.Cells(i - 1, j).Value <> "" And sort.Cells(i, name).Value = "" And a < lastrow Then
    sort.Cells(i - 1, j).Copy
    Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(a, j)).PasteSpecial
End If
If sort.Cells(i - 1, j).Value <> "" And sort.Cells(i, name).Value = "" And a >= lastrow Then
    sort.Cells(i - 1, j).Copy
    Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(lastrow, j)).PasteSpecial
End If
Next j

If sort.Cells(i, name).Value = "" And a < lastrow Then
    sort.Cells(i - 1, name).Copy
    Range(Cells(i, name), Cells(a, name)).PasteSpecial
End If
If sort.Cells(i, name).Value = "" And a >= lastrow Then
    sort.Cells(i - 1, name).Copy
    Range(Cells(i, name), Cells(lastrow, name)).PasteSpecial
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

'''

Comment: If you'll take a moment to take the [tour], you'll note that your post (especially the title) is supposed to tell us _what_ your code does in addition to what you'd like to have fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can improve performance by copying the values from the sheet to an array, processing the array and then copying the values back to the sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub inland3()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim colBuch As Long, colName As Long
    Dim colBuysell As Long, colWKN As Long
    Dim lastcolumn As Long, lastrow As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim ar As Variant, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
   
    Set ws = Worksheets("Inland")
    With ws
        colBuch = .Cells.Find("Orderbuch", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        colName = .Cells.Find("Orderbuchname", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        colBuysell = .Cells.Find("Kauf/Verkauf", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        colWKN = .Cells.Find("WKN", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        lastcolumn = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, colWKN).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    ' scan down filling in blanks with previous value
    Dim pv As Variant
    For c = 1 To lastcolumn
        Select Case c
            Case colBuch, colName, colBuysell, Is > colWKN
                'copy column to array
                ar = ws.Cells(1, c).Resize(lastrow)
                pv = ar(2, 1)
                For r = 2 To UBound(ar)
                    If Len(ar(r, 1)) = 0 Then
                        ar(r, 1) = pv
                    Else
                        pv = ar(r, 1)
                    End If
                Next
                 'copy array back to sheet
                ws.Cells(1, c).Resize(lastrow) = ar
        End Select
    Next

    MsgBox "Updated in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0") & " secs", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: @Kanishk it's appropriate to say "thanks" by clicking the up arrow next to all answers that help you. Give it a few days, there may be more! Then, click the check mark next to the one that helped you the _most_.

Comment: Amazing, much more readable, can I ask for a clarification about why you chose to do `Select Case c` instead of just `If c = ...`? Is Select Case faster, more reliable, or is it just preference?

Comment: @Toddleson  Preference mainly. but also I thought 4 case items reflected the 4 code blocks in the original.